# Getting json-rpc error while sending transaction

Tags: transactions, ethereum, json-rpc, metamask

Hey everyone need some help. When I am trying to communicate with a smart contract I am getting the following error. I can't find the exact reason the transaction is being reverted.

```
Object { code: -32603, message: "Internal JSON-RPC error.", data: {…} }​
  code: -32603
​
  data: Object { code: -32000, message: "execution reverted" }
  code: -32000
  message: "execution reverted"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Can you add code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help someone.

This happened with me I was sending USDT/USDC/BUSD

I am using Flutter + WalletConnect, TrustWallet & Metamask

my request has problem, when sending ERC20 token from Metamask you don't have to send value and chain param in transaction but make sure Metamask is on same network

and for TrustWallet you have to send value : 0 and chainId is must if sending ERC20 token

```
    {
      'from': from,
      'to': contractAddress,
      'data': '0x${contractData.asciiToHex()}',
    };
```